X-REAL-IP nginx reverse proxy spoofing
I have express js API where I need to obtain user IP address.
In nginx I have these settings:
location /api {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;  
}

In express I get ips like this
req.headers['x-real-ip']  

And it works, I really get some IP addresses, but my question is:
Is it real to fake x-real-ip?
Someone every 3 seconds create tnew user with new ip through API and I dont believe someone with 10.000 proxies registrate accounts..

The answer to your question: There is no problem faking x-real-ip, you just add the header, and put whatever you want there.
If you want to make sure this is the real IP of the client you need to set your express server to listen only to requests coming from your nginx server.
If Express's listening port is open to the world - the same IP can send you requests with x-real-ip header with random IPs.
To try block this attacks:

Make sure the Express port is open only to your nginx server (or localhost if it's on the same server)
Check the nginx logs to find this "new user" requests.
Capture the full request, find a common key, maybe user-agent or anything else that can help you pinpoint the attack.
Consider adding extra restriction to create new users, could be some client logic, maybe email auth?

Recommended read: https://serverfault.com/a/381398/218780

There is no problem faking x-real-ip, you just adding the header, and put whatever you want there. Correct, but nginx sets/overrides the header and set its to $remote_addr. So the client can set whatever he wants, nginx overrides it.

That why if you decide to trust the x-real-ip header, you need to make sure all traffic comes only from your trusted nginx.
